# Disabling auto compaction in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

I would like to disable auto compaction on my CouchDB instance - so that I can get a full history of all the database updates.

Is this possible? If so, how do I go about it? Is there a reason why I should not do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the description for how to configure automatic compaction in [section 3.7 of the documentation](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/compaction.html). The basic info regarding the configuration of CouchDB can be found in [section 3.1](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/intro.html).

As I have never turned of automatic compaction and am not sure why you want this, I think you can play around with the settings to achieve it. There is no attribute to set automatic compaction to `false`.

A word of warning: the basic principle of revisions (_rev) in CouchDB is to keep copies of documents for each revision. That means if you have a document sized 100 kb you will consume n * 100 kb disc space where n is the number of revisions. Please keep that in mind and be aware, that with many documents and many changes, your disk will be full very quickly.

Comment: Is there some plugin that will maintain the history for me?